# Cat Breeds - Logic Grid Puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid

You can play this game here: https://www.brainzilla.com/logic/logic-grid/cat-breeds/ Also available [as PDF here](https://www.brainzilla.com/media/logicgrid/pdfs/cat-breeds.pdf).

---

Figure out the age and favorite food of four cats from different breeds. Each cat is wearing a colored collar.

---

- Age: 1, 2, 3, 4
- Breed: Asian, Highlander, Manx, Persian
- Colllar: Black, Green, Pink, White
- Favorite Food: Chicken, Duck, Fish, Turkey

---

1. The ages of the Highlander and the cat with white collar sum up to 6. They don't like fish.
2. The cats with green and pink collar have 1 year of difference. They aren't Persians.
3. The Manx cat is black, or he likes duck.
4. The Persian isn't 3 years old. He doesn't like turkey nor duck.
5. Chicken loving cat is 1 year older than the cat wearing a green collar.
6. The cat with a pink collar is Asian, or he likes duck.
7. The cat with the black collar is 1 year younger than the cat with the green one.

[image: Cat Breeds Logic Puzzle]

Comment: A quick review shows that every puzzle you have posted here has been reposted content from brainzilla.com. While sharing really memorable puzzles found elsewhere is appreciated, it's not really fair (nor fair use) for you to gain rep here by predominantly (or *exclusively!*) posting run-of-the-mill content from other sources, even with attribution. Reposting these logic-grid puzzles is a lot like someone posting a Sudoku book, one puzzle a month... that shouldn't be okay here, for multiple reasons.  May I suggest you try creating some content of your own?

Comment: Hi @Rubio, yes, I understand exactly what you mean. In this case, though, I'm the admin of brainzilla.com. My intention posting this content here is to gain visibility of my website and to provide new content to the community. Please let me know if it's OK to continue doing that or if I should stop.

Comment: @Jamie You might want to take a look here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/promotion which offers some guidelines on what is and isn't appropriate promotional conduct here.

Comment: Actually, a better thing to look at is this one https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4340/how-not-to-be-a-spammer-redux because the one I linked above is a general thing applying to all of Stack Exchange, and PSE is a little different from most SE sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the answer is:

> Asian - Pink collar - 3 yr old - Chicken
> Highlander - Green collar - 2 yr old - Turkey
> Manx - White collar - 4 yr old - Duck
> Persian - Black collar - 1 yr old - Fish

This was fun. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 5):

**Answer**

> \begin{array} {|c|c|c|c|} \hline Breed&Collar&Age&Food\\\hline Asian&Pink&3&Chicken\\\hline Highlander&Green&2&Turkey\\\hline Manx&White&4&Duck\\\hline Persian&Black&1&Fish\\\hline  \end{array}

**Explanation**

1. The ages of the Highlander and the cat with white collar sum up to 6. They don't like fish.
2. The cats with green and pink collar have 1 year of difference. They aren't Persians.
3. The Manx cat is black, or he likes duck.
4. The Persian isn't 3 years old. He doesn't like turkey nor duck.
5. Chicken loving cat is 1 year older than the cat wearing a green collar.
6. The cat with a pink collar is Asian, or he likes duck.
7. The cat with the black collar is 1 year younger than the cat with the green one.

> c2 and c7 tell us black, green, pink so white either 1 or 4. Clue 1 says white is 4. Ages done. Highlander is 2 (c1) and green (logic match).
>  [image: logic_cats_1]

**Then**

> c5 says chicken is 3, therefore pink. c6 says also Asian. Asian, pink, 3,chicken done.
>  [image: logic_cats_2]

**Next**

> c4 says Persian likes duck (he isn't 3 therefore doesn't like chicken). Persian can't be white (c1), so Manx is, and c3 says Manx likes duck.
>  [image: logic_cats_3]

**Finally**

> Highlander doesn't like chicken, so likes turkey. Rest is automatic.

Comment: This well laid-out answer should get at least as much recognition as the earlier unelaborated solution